# What's this data format? It looks like some kind of reduced pseudo-XML/JSON to me

Tags: data-structures, format

Sorry, this might be a dumb question but I have no idea how to google this... I've got output from a CLI tool and I was wondering, what the format is called. I wouldn't want to write a parser myself if it's a common format, and I'm sure it is.

It looks like this;

```
statusList {
  status {
    int  time="1260878400"
    value {
      char value="197773F100"
      char type="RGF"
    } #value
  } #status

  status {
    int  time="1260899700"
    value {
      char value="347663E100"
      char type="RGF"

    } #value
  } #status
} #statusList
```

Thanks!

Comment: You right that you can't google that output, of course, but you can google the tool name (what is it? all you said is it's CLI..) to find its docs or developers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks very much like [JSon](http://www.json.org/) to me. It is not exactly the same, but appears to have most of the same constructs.

Comment: ?? Because it uses curly braces? Because other than that, I'm not seeing it. JSON doesn't use types, doesn't use `=` for initialization, doesn't use newline as a terminator, doesn't allow the same identifer to be repeated at the same level, etc., etc.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like a JSON variant.